# Change order of search results (Siri) on modern iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, spotlight, search, siri

Legacy iOS versions had a Spotlight area in Settings > General to control the order of the results.

I cannot find any such setting on iOS 16. Is it no longer possible? For example, I would like matching "Apps" to be at the top of the results. By default, they are so far at the bottom that I even have to annoyingly tap a "Show More Results" button to see them.